# Get range of dates from dates record in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

I have dates record

```
with DateTable (dateItem) as 
(  
  select  '2022-07-03'  union all
  select  '2022-07-05'  union all
  select  '2022-07-04'  union all
  select  '2022-07-09'  union all
  select  '2022-07-12'  union all
  select  '2022-07-13'  union all
  select  '2022-07-18' 
)
select dateItem  
from DateTable 
order by 1 asc
```

I want to get ranges of dates between this record like this

```
with DateTableRange (dateItemStart, dateItemend) as 
(  
  select  '2022-07-03','2022-07-05'  union all
  select  '2022-07-09','2022-07-09'  union all
  select  '2022-07-12','2022-07-13'  union all
  select  '2022-07-18','2022-07-18' 
 
)
select dateItemStart, dateItemend  
from DateTableRange
```

I am able to do it in SQL with looping using while or looping by getting first one and check the next dates and if they are 1 plus then I add it in enddate and do the same in loop

But I don't know what the best or optimized way is, as there were lots of looping and temp tables involve
Edited :
as in data we have 3,4,5 and 6,7,8 is missing  so range is 3-5

9 exist and 10 is missing so range is 9-9
so ranges is purely depend on the consecutive data in datetable

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Presumably `'2022-07-09','2022-07-09'` should be `'2022-07-04','2022-07-09'`; You'll also need a column that indicates the *ordering* of rows.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different optimization tricks.)

Comment: @Stu 4-9 can not be a range in data as 6,7,8 are missing

Comment: @jarlh sorry i have updated the Question , i was in my zone so didnt thought of that :)

Comment: @Ahmed the range is based on data, as i mentioned in above answer that as 3,4,5 exist and 6 is missing so range is 3-5 , 6,7,8 are missing , so consecutive dates , hope that clarify it

Comment: This explanation should have been in your question @Ahteshamulhaq, it would have helped for your sample data to be presented chronologically.

Comment: @stu i agree , but did it clearify ?

Comment: Seems like this is a "gaps and islands" problem and you can find many discussions about how to solve it with simple searching.

Comment: @SMor i just looked into "Gaps and island" problem but i noticed in that case we already have start and end date , but in my case i have only dates , i need to create start and end myself

Answer (score 0):

After clarification, this is definitely a 'gaps and islands' problem.

The solution can be like this

```
WITH DateTable(dateItem) AS
(  
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES 
        ('2022-07-03'),
        ('2022-07-05'),
        ('2022-07-04'),
        ('2022-07-09'),
        ('2022-07-12'),
        ('2022-07-13'),
        ('2022-07-18')
    ) t(v)
)
SELECT
    MIN(dateItem) AS range_from,
    MAX(dateItem)  AS range_to
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(day, 1, prev_dateItem) >= dateItem THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS range_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateItem) AS rn,
            CAST(dateItem AS date) AS dateItem,
            CAST(LAG(dateItem) OVER (ORDER BY dateItem) AS date) AS prev_dateItem
        FROM DateTable
    ) groups
) islands
GROUP BY range_id
```

You can check a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6536b7c553ab7d3b75bc3b7b1bb6382d)

Comment: its in MS SQL , but your above is not what i want .but as i mentioned , its consecutive range , 3,4,5 exist so its why 3-5 , 6,7,8 are not there so we leave it , now 9 exist but 10 dont , so 9-9 , hope that clear it

Comment: @Ahteshamulhaq, I have updated my answer with new clarification details taken into account

Answer (score 0):

With some additional clarity this requires a gaps-and-islands approach to first identify adjacent rows as groups, from which you can then use a window to identify the first and last value of each group.

I'm sure this could be refined further but should give your desired results:

```
 with DateTable (dateItem) as 
 (  
  select  '2022-07-03'  union all
  select  '2022-07-05'  union all
  select  '2022-07-04'  union all
  select  '2022-07-09'  union all
  select  '2022-07-12'  union all
  select  '2022-07-13'  union all
  select  '2022-07-18' 
), valid as (
   select *,  
     case when exists (
       select * from DateTable d2 where Abs(DateDiff(day, d.dateitem, d2.dateitem)) = 1
     ) then 1 else 0 end v
  from DateTable d
  ), grp as (
    select *,
      Row_Number() over(order by dateitem) - Row_Number() 
        over (partition by v order by dateitem) g
    from Valid v
  )
select distinct
  Iif(v = 0, dateitem, First_Value(dateitem) over(partition by g order by dateitem)) DateItemStart, 
  Iif(v = 0, dateitem, First_Value(dateitem) over(partition by g order by dateitem desc)) DateItemEnd
from grp
order by dateItemStart;
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0ce42df5d111b2b6f5580551ec6ab0e)

Comment: it failed with first test :( with DateTable (dateItem) as 
(  
  select  '2022-07-03'  union all
  select  '2022-07-05'  union all
  select  '2022-07-04'  union all
  select  '2022-07-09'  union all
  select  '2022-07-12'  union all
  select  '2022-07-17'  union all
  select  '2022-07-18' 
)

Comment: please look into     https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8f8db98dd654948090f851e0d2e548a

Comment: @Ahteshamulhaq thanks for the clarification, I've revised the above, does this now work for you?

Comment: thanks for trying again but it again failed  with DateTable (dateItem) as 
     (  
      select  '2022-07-03'  union all
      select  '2022-07-05'  union all
      select  '2022-07-04'  union all
      select  '2022-07-09'  union all
      select  '2022-07-12'  union all
      select  '2022-07-13'  union all
      select  '2022-07-18'  union all
      select  '2022-07-19' 
    )

Comment: try this  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8f8db98dd654948090f851e0d2e548a